# Evaluating $\log(a^2+ab-6b^2)-\log(a^2+4ab+15b^2)$ when $a^2-2ab-9b^2=0$ and $a$, $b$ have the same sign

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Suppose $a$, $b$ have the same sign. What is
> $$\log(a^2+ab-6b^2)-\log(a^2+4ab+15b^2)$$
> when $a^2-2ab-9b^2=0$?

My solution is the following.

Since
$$a^2-2ab-9b^2=0 \implies a^2+ab-6b^2 = 3ab + 3b^2$$ and $$a^2+4ab+15b^2 = 6ab+6b^2$$
therefore, the given logarithm is
$$\log\frac{3(ab+b^2)}{6(ab+b^2)} = \log\frac{1}{2}$$

Because $a$, $b$ have the same sign and not equal to $0$ the logarithm is defined, so I don't find any error in this, but the answer itself is different from mine not just the solution.

Can anybody tell me in which part I choose the wrong path?

Comment: $a^2-2ab-9b^2=0$ means $a=(1\pm \sqrt{10})b,$ but, being the same sign means $a=(1\pm\sqrt{10})b.$

Comment: it clearly states that $a^2-2ab-9b^2=0$ i can add how to book solved the problem if it helps

Comment: If $c=\frac ab=1+\sqrt{10}$ this means you want: $$\log\frac{a^2+ab-6b^2}{a^2+4ab+15b^2}=\log \frac{c^2+c-6}{c^2+4c+15}$$

Comment: yes that's actually how the book solved it what i don't understand is why i can't state that $a^2+ab-6b^2 = 3ab+3b^2$

Comment: Thee rest of the argument was correct, @user1164317. Just copied the equation wrong. No reason the be impatient with the word "clearly," editing comments here is frustrating.

Comment: My mistake, $a^2+ab-6b^2=3ab+3b^2$ is good. But the other would be $a^2+4ab+15b^2 = 6ab+24b^2$.

Comment: i apologize if it sounded like i was rushing

Comment: $$a^2+4ab+15b^2=6ab+24b^2$$ not $6b^2.$ It would be $6b^2$ if the original equation had $\dots+9b^2=0,$ not $\dots-9b^2=0.$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
a^2+ab-6b^2= (a^2-2ab-9b^2)+(3ab+3b^2)= 3b(a+b)\\
\\
a^2+4ab+15b^2=(a^2-2ab-9b^2) + (6ab+\color{red}{24}b^2)=6b(a+\color{red}{4}b)
$$
Therefore,
$$
\log\frac{a^2+ab-6b^2}{a^2+4ab+15b^2}=\log\left( \dfrac{3b(a+b)}{6b(a+\color{red}{4}b)} \right) = \log\left( \dfrac{1(a+b)}{2(a+\color{red}{4}b)} \right)
$$

Answer (score -2):

$$a^2-2ab－9b^2＝0\implies\;a^2-2ab＋b^2＝10b^2\implies\;(a－b)^2＝10b^2\\~\\\implies(a－b)＝\pm\;b\sqrt {10}\implies\;a＝b(\pm\sqrt {10}＋1)$$

And therfore :
$$a^2＋ab－6b^2＝b^2(6\pm3\sqrt {10})$$
$$a^2＋4ab＋15b^2＝b^2(30\pm6\sqrt {10})$$

and Finally :
$$\log(a^2+ab-6b^2)-\log(a^2+4ab+15b^2)＝\log\left({\frac {a^2+ab-6b^2}{a^2+4ab+15b^2}}\right)＝\log\left({\frac {b^2(6\pm3\sqrt {10})}{b^2(30\pm6\sqrt {10})}}\right)＝\log\left({\frac {6\pm3\sqrt {10}}{30\pm6\sqrt {10})}}\right)$$

Comment: "$a$ and $b$ have the same sign", so the ratio is $\sqrt{10}+1$ and not $-\sqrt{10}+1$.